# Failed to run pkg-config with Rust and GTK on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, gtk, gtk3, glib

I have started programming in Rust recently and I love it <3.

I want to make a small desktop application with Rust and GTK. I am on a Windows machine, but I am facing a problem while setting up my environment.

I followed these tutorials:

- [The GTK project, "Setting up GTK for Windows"](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/)
- [Rust bindings for GTK+ 3](https://gtk-rs.org/)

I implemented the code. I am MSYS2 as GTK deliverant. I followed these tutorials step by step, but when I try to compile the code, I get the following error message:

```
"Failed to run `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "glib-2.0" "glib-2.0 >= 2.44"`: The System cant find the given file. (os error 2)"
```

My project working directory looks like this:

```
.  project
├─ Cargo.lock
├─ Cargo.toml
├─ src/
│  └─ main.rs
└─ target/
```

I've currently not set the MSYS2 Directory as `PATH` variable. I've tried this before but with no result.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: [Take a Look here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVopEfWiFX88_zUzk08ZdrIc). At the beginning of the second Video you are going to see those tests. Check them and tell us if there are some problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it. I followed along the mentioned tutorials.
After that one i set the Variable

> GTK_LIB_DIR=C:\msys64\mingew64\bin
> PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1

And set the follwing variable to PATH

> C:\msys64\mingw64\bin

After that, dont forget to restart the Pc, i had quit a Problem with this one. Becuase the variables werent correctly propagated.

I am using the dependecies and features of the following .toml from [github](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/master/Cargo.toml). With this i am compiling for the given feature of gtk_3_24 and for the target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu. So the command looks as following.

> cargo run --features gtk_3_24 --target=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

With this, all works fine :).

Comment: Well, happy GTK coding 

Answer (score 2):

In my case, what resolved it was the solution [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/pkg-config-rs/issues/23#issuecomment-239558109), namely

> pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config

or

> pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config