# Rust compilation error " failed to run custom build command for `freetype-sys v0.13.1' " win 10

Tags: rust, gtk, rust-cargo

I am trying to build a Rust program on Windows 10 having a GUI. When trying to
compile a Rust file with gtk dependency on Windows 10 I keep getting the following error messages.

```
warning: unused manifest key: target.i686-pc-windows-msvc.freetype
warning: unused manifest key: target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.freetype
   Compiling freetype-sys v0.13.1
   Compiling glib-sys v0.10.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/sys#5f35e26c)
error: failed to run custom build command for `freetype-sys v0.13.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `F:\KA_IdeaProjects\KA_Test_rustIProject2\target\debug\build\freetype-sys-66d9e52815699227\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FREETYPE2_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FREETYPE2_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=FREETYPE2_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\3830101\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\freetype-sys-0.13.1\\freetype2" "-G" "Visual Studio 16 2019" "-Thost=x64" "-Ax64" "-DWITH_BZip2=OFF" "-DWITH_HarfBuzz=OFF" "-DWITH_PNG=OFF" "-DWITH_ZLIB=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=F:\\KA_IdeaProjects\\KA_Test_rustIProject2\\target\\debug\\build\\freetype-sys-ef0fda53c071f0de\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_RELEASE= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  failed to execute command: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
  is `cmake` not installed?

  build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\3830101\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.45\src\lib.rs:894:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Like it says in the error: `is 'cmake' not installed?`

Comment: Tried installing cmake 
 using cargo install cmake command and getting the following error message
    Updating crates.io index
error: specified package `cmake v0.1.45` has no binaries

Comment: [cmake](https://cmake.org/) is not a Rust package but a generic build tool that is used to build Freetype (a C library on which GTK depends).

Comment: How to install cmake

Comment: Installed cmake and entered the command "cargo check" and got the following error messages.
error: failed to run custom build command for glib-sys v0.10.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/sys#5f35e26c)
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: F:\KA_IdeaProjects\KA_Test_rustIProject2\target\debug\build\glib-sys-f403e58c78145f13\build-script-build (exit code: 1)
stderr Failed to run "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "glib-2.0" "glib-2.0 >= 2.44": The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2) warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish.. error: build failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935278/failed-to-run-pkg-config-with-rust-and-gtk-on-windows

Comment: I followed the instructions and also updated rsutup and cargo and compiled and got he following error message error[E0599]: the method `connect_activate` exists for struct `gtk::Application`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:15:17
   |
15 |       application.connect_activate(|app| {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `gtk::Application` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: C:\Users\3830101\.cargo\git\checkouts\gtk-b89af3a825b1a0bb\59c3800\src\auto\application.rs:24:1

Comment: So you now have the dependencies installed and compiled. That last message is another issue, so please ask another question for it, after [searching if one of the existing answers applies to your case](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=the+method+exists+but+its+trait+bounds+were+not+satisfied).

Comment: OK.  Thanks for  your help.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you. My problem was resolved using the following command:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423500)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The question is clearly related to Windows. How is this going to help?

Comment: @mydoghasworms Actually, I'm on Windows and it helped me: just used "winget install cmake" instead of apt and that's all.

Comment: @kilj Thanks for the info. Perhaps it would have been useful to update the answer to just reflect the fact that cmake is missing to make it more clear (perhaps with a hint on how to install it on different platforms).

Comment: @CreeLoper27 Please undelete your answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @mydoghasworms Done, tho the answer is still quite incomplete and doesn't cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

The error is due to cmake not being present.

If you use APT as your package manager you can run the following command to install cmake (as that is what you are missing and is causing the error):

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

On Windows, if you have winget installed, you could use

```
winget install cmake
```

You might need to close and reopen your terminal after the installation finishes on Windows.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The question is clearly related to Windows. How is this going to help?